# Return two functions in regular expression

Tags: regex

[In this regex example (\w+\s*([\S\s]*))](https://regex101.com/r/qR4nK4/1) I'm trying to extract function names with their arguments. Given the test string `func1 (1, 2) + func2 (3, 4)` the result should be an array containing two elements `func1 (1, 2)` and `func2 (3, 4)`, still it returns the entire string. What's wrong with this regex?

Comment: Please include also the expression here, not only the link? Also please describe what is your problem it. Questions should be self containing.

Comment: the expression is in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
(\w+\s*\([^)]+\))
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dC5pO0/1)

Output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-12]  `func1 (1, 2)`
MATCH 2
1.  [15-27] `func2 (3, 4)`
```

Explanation:

`[^)]+` match one and unlimited times if not `)` character

`[\S\s]` will match **any** character include `)`, that is your problem